# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Back Screen Freeze

Tags: 22.04, graphics, google-chrome, wayland

I have Ubuntu 22.04 dual booted with Windows 10 in my laptop.

Specifications:

Lenovo ThinkPad E495
  Windowing system: Wayland
  Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 3500u
  Graphics card: AMD® Radeon vega 8 graphics

Whenever I try to do multiple things like open Google Meet or open websites like this [animated Site](https://mastery.games/flexboxzombies/), my laptop just hangs and stops working completely.

To use 2-finger pinch zoom in/out, I have turned on `Preferred Ozone platform` as `Wayland` on `chrome://flags/`, to match the windowing system above. This for some reason also makes my Chrome search bar, and chrome-tab text insanely small.

For now, I have followed [Pheonix's Answer to reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes/36717#36717), and others, but I have no idea what the problem is. I've read that Nvidia drivers cause the problem, but given mine are from amd I don't know what I am doing.

24 January 2024 Update: For now, I have reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04 again since I didn't have much files in the previous session anyways. And have not restarted my laptop to update like I did last time after which the black screen error popped up.

I'll keep on updating this space till I find a solution

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And stick to one question instead of asking multiple questions.

Comment: Thanks. My main problem is black screen freezing. I was just trying to explain the background things, and symptoms around it. Is that okay?

Comment: Is good, same problem here :(